# Paypal Webhooks and AWS API Gateway integration

Tags: aws-api-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

I'm trying to setup Paypal webhooks to notify me on specific events, for example when orders are completed. For the webhook URL I want it to go to my API Gateway resource, where then I want to automatically enter some data into a database (among other stuff) via the use of Lambda functions.

I've setup my API Gateway service (just a rest interface with no authorisation), and i've tested it, and AWS side everything works as it should. Now, when I try and use the "WebHooks Simulator", I'm expecting the webhook to send some data to API Gateway, and then through to my lambda function. Now, this is where something is going wrong. I'm checking my logs on CloudWatch, and nothing is coming through, no errors, no info... Which means there seems to be some connectivity problem from Paypal -> AWS.

As AWS seems to work as expected during my testing, I've decided to reach out here to figure out if anyone has any ideas why it is failing?

Comment: You should first try to manually post some data at your endpoint, if it works or some issue at code level,

Comment: I've mocked out the AWS API Gateway side and it's all fine. I've then enabled my webhook to point at the API Gateway location. Next, I add a transaction for my sandbox app, complete it (state of needs authorising at this point) and then checked API Gateway logs. No calls from Paypal. Confused.

Comment: Is there any log at API Gateway, when you manually post data at endpoint?

Comment: Yeah if I manually send data it appears in the log

Comment: Ok, what is happening when you trigger from "WebHooks Simulator"?

Comment: PayPal says "successful queued" and I see the simulated data below. Then, when I go to AWS and check the logs absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before, as well.  For me, the issue was that the API Gateway was blocking requests due to permissions, returning a 403.

You can [enable API Gateway logging in CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/#:%7E:text=Enable%20logging%20for%20your%20API,Enable%20CloudWatch%20Logs%20check%20box.) to view what's happening at the API level, if the problem is occurring before anything touches the lambda.